# Trigger gitlab downstream pipeline from a upstream pipeline in a multi-project using trigger, rules and custom configuration variables

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this scenario where I want to run the trigger in build stage only when `$FLAG` variable has been set by the `.pre` stage. However, the `build` stage never runs.

How should I conditionally trigger a downstream pipeline?

```
checkArtifactPresent:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - >
      set +e;
      if curl -s -S -f $NEXUS_RAW_PICKER_REPOSITORY/${PRODUCT_FLAVOR}/${PRODUCT_FLAVOR}-${BUILD_TYPE}v${PICKER_TEMPLATE_TAG}.apk --output ${PRODUCT_FLAVOR}-${BUILD_TYPE}v${PICKER_TEMPLATE_TAG}.apk;
      then
        export FLAG= true;
      fi

buildArtifact:
  stage: build
  only:
   variables:
     - $FLAG
  trigger:
   project: dev/project_name
   strategy: depend
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic child pipelines. (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines).

You could create a job for triggering your job "buildArtifact" in a yml-file created with jsonnet in your "checkArtifactPresent".
With using "--ext-str" or "--ext-code" in jsonnet.
You can control the yml-file creation (https://jsonnet.org/learning/tutorial.html#parameterize-entire-config).

Read more https://jsonnet.org/